# Causes of muscular imbalance?

Tags: back, biceps, muscle-imbalance

I've been noticing a slight imbalance with my back for the past few months. It is a very slight difference I.e. when doing 40kg dumbell rows right side feels like it still has 1 or 2 reps in the tank when my left side fails. I've come to beleive the problem is my bicep not my back as its more noticeable with bicep focused exercises. I understand the cause of muscular imbalance so I've used primarily dumbell exercises so my biceps and back are bilaterally isolated and I ALWAYS work until failure on the weaker side and never beyond so if not idea of the cause of this imbalance. What could it be?

Comment: May it be that right is your dominant hand?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yes it is, but I don't have any imbalance whatsoever with chest, shoulder, or tricep exercises

Comment: If anything with dumbell chest press there isn't enough imbalance that I could do more reps on one side but when I reach the last rep before failure I've noticed its actually slightly easier on the left side not the right.

Comment: I'm asking because the neuromuscular pathways esp. for biceps recruitment may just be better honed on the dominant side. I'm not aware of any science on that though, hence no answer.